# Android PJSIP account info

Tags: android, sip, pjsip

I have a sip server with a domain, that looks like 111.111.111.111:1111 (UDP), and there is a conference with 2222 number (i think it's a listening port), to which i should call. Also i have login and password to the sip account: 3333/Test3333. How do i create an account with PJSIP library and call to conference.

This error i get when trying to create an account:

```
FAILED TO CREATE ACCOUNT
java.lang.Exception: Title:       pjsua_acc_add(&pj_acc_cfg, make_default, &
Code:        171039
Description: Invalid URI (PJSIP_EINVALIDURI)    
Location:    ../src/pjsua2/account.cpp:997
```

Here's my pjsip manager class:

```
class PJSipManager {

    private val ep = Endpoint()
    private val acc = SipAccount()
    private var call: SipCall? = null
    private var coroutineScope: CoroutineScope? = null


    private val _callInfoFlow = MutableSharedFlow<CallInfo>()
    val callInfoFlow = _callInfoFlow.asSharedFlow()

    fun initLib(scope: CoroutineScope) {
        coroutineScope = scope
        if (ep.libGetState() == pjsua_state.PJSUA_STATE_NULL) {
            val epConfig = EpConfig()
            epConfig.logConfig.writer = BaseSipViewModel.PJLogger()
            epConfig.logConfig.decor = epConfig.logConfig.decor and
                    (pj_log_decoration.PJ_LOG_HAS_CR or
                            pj_log_decoration.PJ_LOG_HAS_NEWLINE).inv().toLong()
            try {
                ep.libCreate()
                ep.libInit(epConfig)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("PJSIP", "LIB DIDNT CREATED")
            }
            try {
                val sipTpConfig = TransportConfig().apply {
                    port = SIP_LISTENING_PORT.toLong()
                }
                ep.transportCreate(pjsip_transport_type_e.PJSIP_TRANSPORT_UDP, sipTpConfig)

                val accCfg = AccountConfig().apply {
                    idUri = ACC_ID_URI

                }
                acc.create(accCfg, true)
            } catch (e:Exception) {
                Log.e("PJSIP", "FAILED TO CREATE ACCOUNT", e)
            }
            try {
                ep.libStart()
                Log.d("PJSIP", "LIB STARTED")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("PJSIP", "LIB DIDNT STARTED", e)
            }
        }
    }

    fun tryStart() {
        Log.i("PJSIP", "is lib running = ${ep.libGetState() == pjsua_state.PJSUA_STATE_RUNNING}")
        if (ep.libGetState() == pjsua_state.PJSUA_STATE_RUNNING) {
            if (call == null) {
                try {
                    ep.audDevManager().setNullDev()
                    val mCall = SipCall(acc, -1)
                    val prm = CallOpParam(true)
                    mCall.makeCall(CALL_DST_URI, prm)
                    call = mCall
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.e("PJSIP", "FAILED TO CALL", e)
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    ep.hangupAllCalls()
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.e("PJSIP", "FAILED TO hangup CALL", e)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    inner class SipAccount: Account() {

        override fun onIncomingCall(prm: OnIncomingCallParam?) {
            if (prm != null) {
                val mCall = SipCall(acc, prm.callId)
                val ansPrm = CallOpParam(true)
                ansPrm.statusCode =
                    if (call == null) pjsip_status_code.PJSIP_SC_OK else pjsip_status_code.PJSIP_SC_BUSY_HERE
                try {
                    mCall.answer(ansPrm)
                    if (call == null)
                        call = mCall
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    println(e)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    inner class SipCall(acc: Account, callId: Int): Call(acc, callId) {

        private fun getCallInfo(call: Call): CallInfo? {
            var ci : CallInfo? = null
            try {
                ci = call.info
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("Failed getting call info: $e")
            }
            return ci
        }

        override fun onCallState(prm: OnCallStateParam?) {
            val ci : CallInfo = getCallInfo(this) ?: return

            ep.utilLogWrite(3, "MyCall", "Call state changed to: " + ci.stateText)
            coroutineScope.launch {
                _callInfoFlow.emit(ci)
            }
            if (ci.state == pjsip_inv_state.PJSIP_INV_STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                call = null
                ep.utilLogWrite(3, "MyCall", this.dump(true, ""))
            }
        }

        override fun onCallMediaState(prm: OnCallMediaStateParam?) {
            val ci : CallInfo = getCallInfo(this) ?: return
            val cmiv = ci.media
            for (i in cmiv.indices) {
                val cmi = cmiv[i]
                Log.i("PJSIP", cmi.type.toString() + " " + cmi.status.toString())
                if (cmi.type == pjmedia_type.PJMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO &&
                    (cmi.status == pjsua_call_media_status.PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_ACTIVE ||
                            cmi.status == pjsua_call_media_status.PJSUA_CALL_MEDIA_REMOTE_HOLD))
                {
                    /* Connect ports */
                    try {
                        val am = getAudioMedia(i)
                        ep.audDevManager().captureDevMedia.startTransmit(am)
                        am.startTransmit(ep.audDevManager().playbackDevMedia)
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        println("Failed connecting media ports" + e.message)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val ACC_ID_URI = "sip:3333:Test333"
        const val CALL_DST_URI = "sip:111.111.111.111:1111"
        const val SIP_LISTENING_PORT = 2222

    }
}
```

EDIT 1

I figured it out, here's the right URIs for successful connection.

```kotlin
const val ACC_ID_URI = "sip:3333@111.111.111.1111"
const val ACC_REGISTRAR_URI = "sip:111.111.111.1111"
const val CALL_DST_URI = "sip:2222@111.111.111.1111:1111"
const val SIP_LISTENING_PORT = 5061 // this you can specify how you want
```

Also you should specify `registrarUri`, becouse without it sip server wont receive any messages from. Account config should look like this:

```
val accCfg = AccountConfig().apply {
                    idUri = ACC_ID_URI
                    regConfig.registrarUri = ACC_REGISTRAR_URI
                    sipConfig.authCreds.add(
                        AuthCredInfo(
                            "digest" ,
                            "*",
                            "3333",
                            0,
                            "Test3333"
                        )
                    )
                }
```

Comment: try logging your account on thirdparty client like Microsip or linphone and check if your account is getting registered it will help you undertstand the issue. By the look of your URI I can say there is something wrong.